# Why my ListView setOnItemClickListner not working with volley android?

Tags: java, android

I have a problem on ListView I'm using setOnItemClick Listener but it doesn't work. Review my code if you found any solution on this and i'm using volley to retrieve the data. But the data is already there and retrieve

This is my Transaction Adapter:

```
public class TransactionAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<TransactionList> list;
    LayoutInflater inflater;

    public TransactionAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<TransactionList> list) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() { return list.size(); }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) { return list.get(position); }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TransactionHander handler = null;
        if(convertView==null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_transaction_data, null);
            handler = new TransactionHander();
            handler.tracking_code =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.track_code);
            handler.tracking_fee =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.track_fee);
            handler.tracking_status =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.track_status);
            convertView.setTag(handler);
        }else{
            handler=(TransactionHander) convertView.getTag();
            handler.tracking_code.setText(list.get(position).getTrack_code());
            handler.tracking_fee.setText(list.get(position).getTrack_fee());
            handler.tracking_status.setText(list.get(position).getTrack_status());
         }

        return convertView;
    }

    static class TransactionHander {
        TextView tracking_code,tracking_fee,tracking_status;
    }
}
```

`TransactionActivity`:

```
public class TransactionActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    ListView lv;
    TextView track_code;
    SharedPreferences pref;
    ArrayList<TransactionList> list = new ArrayList<>();
    TransactionAdapter adapter;

    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @SuppressLint("WrongViewCast")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_transaction);
        pref = getSharedPreferences("user_details", MODE_PRIVATE);
        this.lv = findViewById(R.id.TransactionList);
        this.adapter = new TransactionAdapter(this, list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Transactions");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new 
        ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#fefefe")));
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide `TransactionAdapter` Code. In my opninion `XML` won't be necessary for this question - you could remove it to reduce size of post.

Comment: Please provide the full code for your adapter and main activity along with your error log

Comment: i had already edit my post